# Owl carousel 2 не работает с табами - как поправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 [owl carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/), каждый в своем табе.

В первой вкладке слайдер работает должным образом, но как только перехожу на вторую вкладку, то слайдер отображается некорректно: все сбивается в кучу.
Как я понимаю, это возникает из-за того, что первый таб скрыт.
В первой версии owl carousel, говорят, такой проблемы не возникает, но мне нужна именно вторая из-за некоторых фич.

Пробую навесить на ивент переключения таба перезагрузку OWL-carousel `trigger('refresh.owl.carousel')`, но что-то делаю неправильно, т.к. эфеекта никакого не наблюдается..

Как поправить? [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/Epmwx/277/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 3
      }
    }
  });

  $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 3
      }
    }
  });
  $(".nav-tabs>li.active").click(function() {
    $(".owl-carousel").trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<div class="tabbable">
  <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
      <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>6</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
      <div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>6</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В каком браузере наблюдается проблема? В Firefox и Opera никакого сваливания в кучу на приведенном примере нет.

Comment: @VenZell проблема на сайте, а в демо хоть и работает вопреки, но ругается на ошибки и строку с триггером - вот и думаю, что что-то неправильно делаю

Comment: Я не вижу никаких ошибок в консоли в данном примере. Вам стоит собрать пример, на котором будет воспроизводится ошибка. Пока нечего анализировать, только гадать. Вы же и сами видите, что в текущем коде нет ошибок

Comment: @VenZell если прописать `console.log` сразу после триггера, то на сайте он отображется только при возврате на исходный первый таб, а не каждый раз - почему так?

Comment: @VenZell ошибка теперь видна - первоначально я по случайности подключил первую карусель

Comment: я не зря удалил теги. Они мало относятся к вашему вопросу. Пожалуйста, не добавляйте их снова. Вашу проблему я изучу подробнее, если вы предоставите текст ошибки. У меня до сих пор в консоли пусто.

Comment: спасибо. @VenZell а я их не зря повторно написал в вопросе - у меня непосредственно код `html` и слайдеры - даже не понимаю почему вы постоянно их вычеркиваете. обратите, пожалуйста, внимание, что при переключении на таб цифры все сбиваются в кучу и располагаются в одном слайде, хотя должны в отдельных. если вызвать редактор кода f12, то карусель обновляется и слайды отображаются так, как и должны

Comment: Потому что ваш вопрос хоть и содержит код `html`, спрашиваете вы не о нем. А метки `slider` и `карусель` слишком общие

Comment: @VenZell по ссылке http://boats.likemedia.by/ на главной в блоке `успей купить/акции` при переключении на вкладку `акции` на части компов карусель инициализируется  гуд, на части, только если зайти под вкладкой инкогнито хорошо, а в прямом режиме нет, а на части компов при переключении все сваливается в кучу.. что за ошибка может возникать?